# How to set environment for adobe air in worklight?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am working on a Worklight hybrid application.I want to know how to set path for adobe air...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the training materials and user documentation?
[Read this topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/devenv/t_installing_tools_for_adobe_air.html).

> - Download the Adobe AIR SDK from the Adobe website at http://www.adobe.com/.
> - Unpack the archive into a folder of your choice.
> - Set an environment variable (either locally or on the central build server) named AIR_HOME, pointing to the place where you opened the
>     SDK. The Worklight® Builder uses this environment variable to run the
>     build and sign tool when building AIR applications.

For example, in my Mac the path is `/Users/idanadar/Documents/Worklight/Setup/Adobe`.
Likewise, in your setup point it to the root folder of the extracted Adobe installation.